# How to create new tables to existing database at run time using EF CodeFirst without using package management console

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

First of all excuse me for my poor English knowledge.

I have an Asp.Net MVC application using EF CodeFirst.I have a module which named : Report and is created as an Area in a separated project.

This module has some needed models to work and I want to add these models as Table to my original database when my module would be called for the first time(eg. suppose I have a controller named : Home including an Action method named : Index in module Report which would be called like Report/Home/Index from the browser)

Now my question here is :

How can I add needed tables to my database without migrations operation using Package-Management-Console.I want this operation would be run automatically and NOT manually.

Thank you for spending time.

Comment: Why do you want "without migrations"? This is exactly the situation they are for

Comment: @Vlad274 see!, when we use EF CodeFirst our database would be created at First access to related DataContext,right? Now I want to add needed tables to my existing tables in lazy loading manner ( at first access  to my module ), got it?